# How to run Skulpt.org on localhost / local server by XAMPP

Tags: python, server, skulpt

Hi i want to measure execution time of basic operations like range etc. on Skulpt(Python in browser)
I know thath Skulpt.org have interactive console online, but the thing is that I want to do it on my local machine, on my local server created by XAMPP.

I have this simple code:

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    a = 1
print("assignment.py", time.time()-t0)
```

How can I run it on simple webpage index.html on my local server using Skulpt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answer.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Skulpt</title>
<script src="skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
```

To folder with index.html you must add 2 files:

> skulpt.min.js
>
> skulpt-stdlib.js